# How to create File object from cloudinary url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to achieve to create a File object from a URL. I tried hard but didn't find a solution to resolve this issue. Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue?

**code**

```
  let blobImages =
  nextProps &&
  nextProps.input &&
  nextProps.input.value &&
  nextProps.input.value.map((item) => {
    let file = new File([item.url], { type: 'image/png' })
    return file
  })
```

I am using this code but this code doesn't work it give me break image result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="myImage"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// Accept an external ArrayBuffer from a service (cloud,external server etc.)
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// For testing lets say this is your URL
request.open( "GET", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Circle-icons-computer.svg/512px-Circle-icons-computer.svg.png", true );

// Identify that your response has declared as arraybuffer
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

// If you are using DOM object, definitelly you will use blob to create your file object 
request.onload = function( e ) {
   
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
  
    // Parse and create your image from url
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    
    // Access your div element, where your photo will be presented.
    // Here instead you can alter the code to download the image as file...
    var img = document.querySelector( "#myImage" );
    img.src = imageUrl;
};

request.send();
```